# javascript is not being load on mobile browser

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble to run a javascript code on my mobile browser, I don't know why, on desktop runs just fine, but when I try to open on my mobile browser it says that couldn't find my variable or my functions function. The object usuario that I'm setting the values is a global object that I created earlier.[how it's shown on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH6Mn.png)[how it's shown on my desktop browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPSHB.png)

```
class UsarioDAO{
    static async trazDadosUsuario(id){
        const dados = await 
        firebase.database().ref("usuarios/"+id).once("value");
        usuario.setUsuarioId(dados.val().usuarioId);
        usuario.setNome(dados.val().nome);
        usuario.setPais(dados.val().pais);
        usuario.setFoto(dados.val().foto);
        usuario.setEmail(dados.val().email);
        usuario.setFotoProvedor(dados.val().fotoProvedor);
        usuario.setCaminho(dados.val().caminho);
        usuario.setToken(dados.val().token);
        usuario.setUsuarioGostos(dados.val().gostos);
        pais = dados.val().pais;
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>resolve("resolvido"));
    }
}
class EventoDAO{
    static async listar(id){

        let eventos = [];

        const eventosRef = firebase.database().ref("eventos/"+pais);


        try{
            const user = await userRef.once("value");

            const categorias = await eventosRef.once("value");
            categorias.forEach(auxEvento=>{
                const evento = new Evento();
                evento.setId(auxEventos.val().id);
                evento.setTitulo(auxEventos.val().titulo);
                evento.setDescricao(auxEventos.val().descricao);
                evento.setHorario(auxEventos.val().horario);


               eventos.push(evento);
           });



        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>resolve(eventos));

        }catch(erro){

            console.log(erro);

            Notificacao.erro(erro);

         }
    }

 }
try{
    await UsuarioDAO.trazDadosUsuario(user.uid,null);
    const eventos = await EventoDAO.listar(user.uid);
    escondeLoading()

    eventos.forEach(evento=>{

        criaLista(evento,"todos");

    });    

    defineLanguage();
    if(navigator.language.split("-").shift()=="en"){
        $(".btn-success").css("padding","30px 30px");
        $(".btn-primary").css("padding","30px 8px");
    }
}catch(erro){
    console.log(erro);
    Notificacao.erro(erro);
}

}
```

Comment: This isn't enough information. Which variable? Which browser? Please share a [mcve] and the exact error message. Thank you.

Comment: it says ReferenceError can't find variable: UsuarioDAO, I tested on chrome, safari and firefox, btw UsuarioDAO is my class and listar is a static method

Comment: You have to tell us what is UsuarioDAO.

Comment: It’s a class with a static method that returns an promise with an array of events that were retrieved from firebase

Comment: Please show all relevant variables so we can reproduce the problem. If the program isn't runnable, it's difficult to get you an answer. See [mcve] and please strip the code down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: someone there? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I "solved" the problem, it seems a compatibility with browsers versions, I ran on chrome from an android phone and it worked, but when I ran on Iphone chrome it doesn't. Also there is something called babel that rewrites your javascript in older versions to work on old browsers versions but still didn't work for me